# How to bind a selected row's first column value to a variable and use it in an SQL Command in QT?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Here is my code, it crashes on button click:

```
QSqlQueryModel*Acceuil::consulter_evenements()
{

 QSqlDatabase bd= QSqlDatabase::database();

 QSqlQueryModel * model=new QSqlQueryModel();

 model->setQuery("SELECT E.* FROM EVENEMENT AS E JOIN CATALOGUES_EVENEMENTS as CE JOIN CATALOGUES as C ON C.ID_Catalogue = CE.ID_Catalogue AND E.ID=CE.ID_Evenement AND C.ID_Catalogue='"+ui->listeCatalogues->selectionModel()->selectedRows(0).at(0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()+"' GROUP BY ID_Catalogue");

 return model;
}
```

I tried binding "ui->listeCatalogues->selectionModel()->selectedRows(0).at(0).data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()" to a QString but it crashed as well.

Replacing the query with a simple one such as "SELECT * FROM EVENEMENT" did not work as well.

Comment: You need to find out which of the many calls that you nested crashes. What is the error message on the console? Try to run it in a debugger. Could be that there are no Rows selected.

Comment: It just crashes with no error message. But it could be that there are no rows selected because I wanted to test the button.

Answer (score 0):

When you use  *model->setQuery( ... )* you should use QSqlQuery as argument. 
Create *QSqlQuery* object. Bind all values to query with *QSqlQuery::bindValue* or similar methods. And only after that make *model->setQuery( queryWithMybindedValues )*